# how to summarize this string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, escaping

i want summarize this line in javascript!
how  is it possible?

```
 var c='['+']'+'('+')'+';'+':'+'<'+'>'+
'='+'<='+'/='+'>='+'+'-'+'&'+'*'+'/'+'=>';
```

I searched for character escapes but i found nothing!

Comment: What do you mean by "summarize this line"?

Comment: hi i want create a min JavaScript .js file for syntax-highlighting plugin for VHDL. i'm not web programmer!! I want to make it like var c =" \[ \] \( \) \< \; \+"

Comment: You can't summarize invalid code no matter how good you are. That thing is just one big syntax error.

Comment: You can try not adding "+" in between everything. `'[]();:<>=<=\/=>=+'-&*\/=>'`

Comment: What you'd end up with without the errors is just `var c = '[]();:<>=<=/=>=+-&*/=>'`, so I don't see the point?

Comment: @adeneo You forgot to escape the "/"

Comment: Im not web developer!! please help! I know it has syntax error! but i want it a one string with character escapes that i dont know!

Comment: hi they must have a balnk ' ' between each character!

Comment: @Shawn31313 Why do you need to escape `/`? Only `'` and `\\` need to be escaped.

Comment: Are you asking how to write a regular expression that matches each of those character sequences?

Comment: @user2601133, you can use something like this `c = "";for(var i =33;i<48;i++){c+=String.fromCharCode(i);}` result is `"!"#$%&'()*+,-./"`

Comment: @Barmar Oh yes, oops. Ha, mixed that up.

Comment: I dont want all char code! I want to have an array of VHDL operator sperated by space!

Comment: "\[ \] \) \( \; \: \< \> \= \<\= \/\= \>\= \+ \- \& \* \/ \=\>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
var opr_re = /\[|\]|\(|\)|;|:|<|>|=|<=|\/=|>=|\+|-|&|\*|\/|=>/;
```

`\` is the escape character in regular expressions.

Comment: thanks i forget to mention this var is to be sent to RegExp Object

Comment: An object that starts with `/` IS a RegExp object.